# Batch file - loop through first n lines of text file

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to determine the format of a text file by looping through the first 10 lines, perform some regex matching and then compare the results at the end. I can easily loop through the entire file, but I only want the first N lines (in this case 10)

I'm familiar with other languages, but the idiosyncrasies of this batch file is throwing me for a loop so to say.

Here is what I have so far:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set /A REGEXCOUNTER=0
set /A COUNTER=0
for /F %A in (%submitfile%) do ( 
  set /A COUNTER=COUNTER+1
  rem echo %A
  setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
  echo(%A|findstr /r /c:"[0-9].*" >nul && (
  set /A REGEXCOUNTER=REGEXCOUNTER+1
  echo %COUNTER% - %REGEXCOUNTER% - FOUND - %A 
      rem any commands can go here
  ) || (
      echo NOT FOUND
      rem any commands can go here
  )


  rem LOOP END

  if %COUNTER% GEQ 10 do (goto loop_over)
  )
)
:loop_over
echo "END HERE!"
```

I've got counters set up that incrementally tick up to count my matches and how many times it's looped. However here is some sample output of variable values:

```
110 - 0 - FOUND - 003
220 - 0 - FOUND - 2
330 - 0 - FOUND - 1
440 - 0 - FOUND - 029
```

The loop counter variable is increasing by ten for each loop and the regex match counter is not going up at all. I'm pretty sure this has something to do with variable scope but I'm not sure where to begin.

Comment: You already have delayed expansion enabled at the top of your script.  Why are you doing it again inside your `FOR` command?  You need to double your percent symbols for your FOR variables.  Says so right in the help file.  You need to reference your environmental variables with exclamation marks. `echo !COUNTER! - !REGEXCOUNTER! `

Comment: There is no `DO` with the `IF` command.  Again, read the help file for the syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should fix all the issues I talked about in my comments above.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set /A REGEXCOUNTER=0
set /A COUNTER=0
for /F %%A in (%submitfile%) do ( 
  set /A COUNTER=COUNTER+1
  rem echo %%A
  echo(%%A|findstr /r /c:"[0-9].*" >nul && (
  set /A REGEXCOUNTER=REGEXCOUNTER+1
  echo !COUNTER! - !REGEXCOUNTER! - FOUND - %%A 
      rem any commands can go here
  ) || (
      echo NOT FOUND
      rem any commands can go here
  )


  rem LOOP END

  if !COUNTER! GEQ 10 goto loop_over
  )
)
:loop_over
echo "END HERE"
```

Comment: Thank you. This does exactly what I need!

Answer (score 0):

1. The extra `setlocal` within the loop should be removed. Once `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` has been executed, it remains in effect until a `setlocal disabledelayedexpansion` is executed or until the batch terminates.
2. Each `%A` (the loop-control *metavariable* must be `%%A` (one `%` if run from the command-line, two if within a batch file)
3. If you change the value of a variable within the loop, then you need to refer to the *changed* value as `!varname!`, not `%varname%` which is the *original* value (search SO for `delayed expansion`). `set /a` always works on the *current* variable value.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I think part of the problem was I was trying to copy and paste it into the command line (I was using the single     %, but still)  which was resulting in things not working correctly. The !variable! in the echo was displaying literally and not the actual value.